# TreeView width unexpectedly changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I have a Frame that contains Treeview and a Frame-embedded-in-a-Canvas.
Treeview displays documents from MongoDB in one `'#0'` column and every time a user selects any document I generate from document's fields a list of Checkbuttons in the Frame-embedded-in-a-Canvas.

The issue I got is that Treeview width is not constant, but I just can't understand why it changes and when exactly it happens.
Every time after generating new Checkbuttons list my Treeview width grows by 30 pixels without any regard to the fact that both the Treeview and the Frame-embedded-in-a-Canvas are expected to be in parent's grid columns 0 and 1 respectively with zero weight.

Here's a [link](https://gfycat.com/pastelsoreequine) to the GIF showing how it looks. And below you can find my code concerning these widgets.

Show me please where to look for this issue reason.

```py
def treeview_reload():
    dt_tv.delete(*dt_tv.get_children())
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_b_', text='biomes')
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_z_', text='zones')
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_p_', text='points')
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_m_', text='biomaterials')
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_c_', text='characters')

def tv_sel_handler(event):
    try:
        sel_iid = event.widget.selection()[0]
    except IndexError:
        sel_iid = ''
    try:
        generate_model(MAP[sel_iid])
    except KeyError:
        pass

def generate_model(document, new_list=True, row=0, indent=0):
    if new_list:
        for c in list(dt_model.children.values()):
            c.destroy()
    i = row
    for field in document.keys():
        if type(document[field]) is list:
            cb = ttk.Label(dt_model, text=indent*2*' '+field)
            cb.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w', padx=30, pady=4)
            cb['font'] = ("Noto Mono", 13)
        else:
            cb = ttk.Checkbutton(dt_model, text=indent*2*' '+field)
            cb.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')
            ttk.Style().configure('Mono.TCheckbutton', font=("Noto Mono", 13))
            cb['style'] = 'Mono.TCheckbutton'
            if type(document[field]) is dict:
                i = generate_model(document[field], False, i+1, indent+1)
    if i > 17:
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(pdb_data, orient=VERTICAL, command=dt_canv.yview)
        dt_canv['yscrollcommand'] = vsb.set
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsw')
        dt_model.bind('<Configure>',
                      lambda event, canvas=dt_canv:
                            canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
        dt_model.bind('<Enter>',
                      lambda event:
                            dt_canv.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",
                                             lambda event:
                                                    dt_canv.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")))
        dt_model.bind('<Leave>',
                      lambda event: dt_canv.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>"))
    return i


# ...
# ___ frame for the data
pdb_data = ttk.Frame(page_db, width=1250, height=450)
pdb_data.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew', pady=24)
# ____ categorized documents list
dt_tv = ttk.Treeview(pdb_data, selectmode='browse', show=('tree',))
dt_tv.column('#0', width=250)
dt_tv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
dt_tv.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', tv_sel_handler)
treeview_reload()
# ____ auxiliary canvas
dt_canv = Canvas(pdb_data, borderwidth=0, width=200)
dt_canv.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw', padx=5)
# _____ frame-embedded-in-a-canvas for checkbuttons list
dt_model = ttk.Frame(pdb_data, takefocus=0)
dt_canv.create_window((0,0), window=dt_model, anchor='nw')

pdb_data.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way how to prevent unexpected Treeview column width change. My solution is to remove Treeview from grid, then explicitly set column width and once again grid Treeview. The code is below.

But couldn't understand a reason of such behaviour. Any explanation is appreciated.

```py
def treeview_reload():
    dt_tv.delete(*dt_tv.get_children())
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_b_', text='biomes')
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_z_', text='zones')
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_p_', text='points')
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_m_', text='biomaterials')
    dt_tv.insert('', 'end', '_c_', text='characters')

def tv_sel_handler(event):
    try:
        sel_iid = event.widget.selection()[0]
    except IndexError:
        sel_iid = ''
    try:
        generate_model(MAP[sel_iid])
    except KeyError:
        pass

def generate_model(document, new_list=True, row=0, indent=0):
    # do not destroy Checkbuttons if recursive call
    if new_list:
        for c in list(dt_model.children.values()):
            c.destroy()
    i = row
    for field in document.keys():
        if type(document[field]) is list:
            cb = ttk.Label(dt_model, text=indent*2*' '+field, font=("Noto Mono", 13))
            cb.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w', padx=30, pady=4)
        else:
            ttk.Style().configure('Mono.TCheckbutton', font=("Noto Mono", 13))
            cb = ttk.Checkbutton(dt_model,
                                 text=indent*2*' '+field,
                                 style='Mono.TCheckbutton')
            cb.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='w')
            if type(document[field]) is dict:
                i = generate_model(document[field], False, i+1, indent+1)
    # only for recursive call
    if not new_list:
        return i
    # this is here because Treeview width changes if grid only once
    dt_tv.grid_remove()
    dt_tv.column('#0', width=220)
    dt_tv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
    # place vertical Scrollbar if needed and connect MouseWheel
    if i > dt_canv.winfo_height() // 28:
        vsb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsw')
        dt_model.bind('<Configure>',
                      lambda event, canvas=dt_canv:
                            canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
        dt_model.bind('<Enter>',
                      lambda event:
                            dt_canv.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",
                                             lambda event:
                                                    dt_canv.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")))
        dt_model.bind('<Leave>',
                      lambda event: dt_canv.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>"))
    else:
        dt_canv.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>')
        dt_model.unbind_all('<Configure>')
        vsb.grid_remove()


# ...
# ___ frame for the data
pdb_data = ttk.Frame(page_db, width=1250, height=450)
pdb_data.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew', pady=24)
# ____ categorized documents list
dt_tv = ttk.Treeview(pdb_data, selectmode='browse', show=('tree',))
dt_tv.column('#0', width=250)
dt_tv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
dt_tv.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', tv_sel_handler)
treeview_reload()
# ____ auxiliary canvas
dt_canv = Canvas(pdb_data, borderwidth=0, width=200)
dt_canv.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw', padx=5)
# _____ frame-embedded-in-a-canvas for checkbuttons list
dt_model = ttk.Frame(pdb_data, takefocus=0)
dt_canv.create_window((0,0), window=dt_model, anchor='nw')
# ____ vertical scrollbar for frame
vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(pdb_data, orient=VERTICAL, command=dt_canv.yview)
dt_canv['yscrollcommand'] = vsb.set

pdb_data.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: looks like you guys are dead there – I should take a glance in the window, perhaps I missed Z-day